# Magento: Fixed shipping cost BELOW certain basket price

Tags: magento

How can I set the shipping cost for Magento for all baskets that are below a certain point. For example, all baskets under £5 have fixed shipping of £1.99.

Comment: Thats flat rate shipping your talking about. Is it the community edition you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i've managed to get it working is to add an extra case statement in my shipping module.

```
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

...
} else if ($request->getPackageValue() < 6) {
    $price = '1.99';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping) is what you are looking for, unless I have the wrong thing. It seems to be called Table Rate Shipping.

Comment: how do i then use a different system over £5?